# DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

This is the schema I am using in the application:
[image]

I'm getting a DuplicateKeyException when trying to insert a Post when it's User already exists in the database. I'm setting the Post's User to the entity that I retrieve from the database, but when I insert the new Post I get the exception saying that it's User is already in use.

Here's the code that is setting the reference to the existing User entity:

```
private void setReferencedEntities(Post post)
{
    User user = (from u in dataContext.Users
                 where u.id == post.CommonColumn.User1.id
                 select u).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user != default(User))
    {
        post.CommonColumn.User1 = user;
    }
}
```

The above function is called like this:

```
foreach (Post post in newPosts)
{
    setReferencedEntities(post);
}
dataContext.Comments.InsertAllOnSubmit(newPosts);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

EDIT:
I'm still having this issue so I thought I would give some more information.
I have this application running on a server 24/7 without issues. When I delete everything from the database on my local machine and run the application I do not have any problems.
The problem occurs when I copy all data from my server database and insert it into my local database. I receive the DuplicateKeyException when trying to insert a new Post using LINQ to SQL.

This test works without issues:

1. Delete everything from local database
2. Run application which generates around 20 Posts, with around 200
   Comments and Replies
3. Run SQL script to delete one Post and all of its associated data
4. Run application again to add the one deleted Post and all of its
   associated data back into the database

This test doesn't work:

1. Delete everything from local database
2. Copy all data from server database
3. Run SQL script to delete one Post and all of its associated data
4. Run application again to add the one deleted Post and all of its associated data back into the database -> this fails with a DuplicateKeyException

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to insert the post again, try just setting the post id on the comment object.

Comment: This did not fix my issue. I've added some more information.

Comment: Which primary key is being violated?